# How can I use vim's key bind in the menu of NERDTree?

Tags: vim, terminal, tmux, nerdtree, iterm2

I'm using iTerm2, tmux, vim and NERDTree.

[NERDTree GitHub](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree)

There is a problem in the menu.

When I push 'm', I can use menu mode.

In menu mode, I cannot use vim's key binding.
(I mean hjkl.)

How can I use it??
Are there plugins or shortcuts??

Answer (score 0):

NERDTree implements its menu (`:help NERDTreeMenu`) by `:echo`ing it to the status line and querying for keys. As indicated in its header, you can only use <kbd>J</kbd> / <kbd>K</kbd> for navigation, or you directly select an entry by pressing the `(o)` highlighted shortcut key (that is determined by the menu definition).

```
NERDTree Menu. Use j/k/enter and the shortcuts indicated
==========================================================
(o)pen through shell
> (a)dd a childnode
(m)ove the current node
(d)elete the current node
```

The key is obtained via this code:

```
:echo nr2char(getchar())
```

You can try this yourself; it should return the key you've pressed after its invocation. If that doesn't work, your terminal is broken (or there's a bug inside Vim).